# cgi bash script not waiting for all output of command

Tags: apache, bash, cgi

I have a cgi script running but I am having issues with the cgi script not waiting for all of the output of the commands.

Here is the cgi script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo Content-type: text/plain
echo ""

case "$QUERY_STRING" in
  start)
    service servicename start
    ;;
  stop)
    service servicename stop
    ;;
  restart)
    service servicename restart
    ;;
  backup)
    service servicename backup
    ;;
  checkisup)
    service servicenamet checkisup
    ;;
  status)
    service servicename status
    ;;
  *)
  echo "Usage: $0 {checkisup|start|stop|restart|backup|status|restart}"
  exit 1
  ;;
esac

exit 0
```

When i call the status with `script.cgi?status`

it executes the status function form my service

```
  if pgrep -u $USERNAME -f $SERVICE > /dev/null
  then
    pre_log_len=`wc -l "$PATH/server.log" | awk '{print $1}'`
    echo "$SERVICE is running... executing command"
    as_user "screen -p 0 -S screenname -X eval 'stuff \"$command\"\015'"
    sleep .1
    tail -n $[`wc -l "$PATH/server.log" | awk '{print $1}'`-$pre_log_len] "$PATH/server.log"
  fi
```

The part i am having the issue with is when the function gets to `sleep .1` the cgi script will just continue without waiting for the output of tall.

Any ideas?

Comment: `sleep .1`, maybe good for a working system, but can't help in debugging this situation. Try `sleep 10` and see if that changes things. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You may not be seeing any output from `tail` because the result of your arithmetic for the `-n` argument may be 0:

```
anew@Wintermute:work$ wc -l dev-configuration.json 
     105 dev-configuration.json
anew@Wintermute:work$ tail -n 0 dev-configuration.json 
anew@Wintermute:work$
```

Comment: Yes but it is not zero when i run the command in terminal,
I thought this could have been the issue too so i set the sleep time to 1 sec but that still did not help.

Comment: Bummer. I'd still troubleshoot it by setting the `tail -n 5` or a similar static value to validate that. I'd say that's your culprit if their haven't been any additions to your logfile. Throw an if/else in there if there's no change to the logfile size output a warning or something. Hope it helps.

Comment: I think I found the issue, the cgi scrip is running at the Apache user an it can't access the file. But I thought it would output that error, apparently not.